# trouble including Google APIs client library for PHP on Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-platform

I am attempting to use the Google PHP library on App Engine, but am having trouble getting the include paths correct.

From the instructions here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/installation I am adding

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/google-api-php-client/src');
```

to my code, but It does not seem to include the files properly.
 I get errors on `include 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';` mainly

```
 PHP Warning:  include(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
 File(/base/data/home/apps/.../google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php) is not within the allowed path(s)
```

I have tried more creative methods such as:

`set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/google-api-php-client/src');`

but to no avail. Everything works fine on localhost, but presumably because it doesn't have the same include path restrictions.

any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: As the default include_path includes the app's root, you shouldn't need to alter it before including `google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php`

Comment: I agree in premise, but the documentation indicates you should add the `set_path_include` line. Also what would be the explanation as to what is causing the PHP warning?

Answer (score 1):

The root of my error was that I was deploying with git commits (which wasn't tracking the `google-api-php-client` folder), not using the deploy script directly. When I deployed from the GoogleAppEngineLauncher, everything worked as expected.